# C++ template function which can take Eigen::vector or std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector, eigen

I was using std::vector in my program and now I made a realization that Eigen::VectorXd will reduce my task in great deal. So I shifted to using Eigen. But I don't want to change the program entirely so I thought of using Templates for some previously defined functions.

I'm new to C++ and template programming is little bit confusing I'm not able to think beyond the below program which is  wrong.

```
using namespace Eigen;
template<class T>
T getvec(T& var)
{
    T res;
    res[0] = var[0]*3;
    res[1]=var[1]*3;
     res[2]=var[2]*3;
    return res;
}

int main(){


    std::vector<double> a(3,1);
    Eigen::VectorXi b(3);
    b.setOnes();

     auto x= getvec(a);
    auto y=getvec(b);
    }
```

Is it possible to write a template function which can take std::vector or Eigen::VectorXd as paramters?

I am in need of a of function as below which can take both type.

```
std::vector<double> getTransform(std::vector<double>& vec)
{
     std::vector<double> res;
     res[0] = vec[0]*3.14;
     ...........
     ...........
     return  res;
}
```

Comment: "*... which is obviously wrong.*" It's not obvious to me. How is it wrong?

Comment: You do not need `&b` and `&c` in the calls.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: 1) `std::vector<double> b[3];` An array of 3 vectors?  2) `auto y=getvec(&b);` -- Why are you passing the address of the item here, when the function takes a reference?

Comment: C array can not be used, since function cannot return array type 'double [3]'.

Comment: can you please provide the #include directives to make this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <typename T>
T  getTransform(const T& vec)
{
    T res;
    res.resize(vec.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size_t(vec.size()); ++i)
    {
        res[i] = vec[i]*3.14;
    }
    return  res;
}
```

Comment: This should work. Only minor problem is that Eigen uses `ptrdiff_t` as return type of `.size()` which is signed. So compilers might warn about signed-unsigned comparison. But the ideal pure Eigen version would be `return 3.14*vec;` anyways.

Comment: Thanks... added cast to size_t arround vec.size()